# Android SD card path inaccessible

Tags: android

I have a knock off android device HT-PAD1051

But, really having trouble accessing the root directory in the built in sd card.  card is partitioned and what is called "mnt/extsd" is accessible.  Any ideas on how to get at root?

The device has been rooted.

Thanks

Joe

Comment: are you talking about getting access to the SD card thought Java code , or browsing the files within a file manager?

Answer (score 1):

For any android device, If you want to get external storage always use.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

instead of **giving hard coded path**.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void writeFile(String text){
        try{
            Writer output = null;
            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/RequiredDirectory");
            dir.mkdirs();

            File file = new File(dir,<filename>);
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
            output.write(text);
            output.close();
            System.out.println("Your file has been written");  
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: did it solve your problem... if yes would you mind indicating my answer as the answer to your problem.. if no... can you please tell me what you have tried,